# An example of right livelihood

Tags: reference-request

A little [reference-request](/questions/tagged/reference-request) question.

As I remember it it's the story of someone who supported his aged parents. He did this by taking loose river clay -- without digging it -- making it into pots, and leaving the pots, without setting a price. People would take the pots and leave in exchange whatever they chose to, and thus he supported his parents. This was portrayed as praise-worthy, ethical.

It's perhaps not a sutta but, I don't know, perhaps one of the stories from the Dhammapada or something like that. Or possibly it's later but I thought it was from the Pali canon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the story of the lay potter Ghatikara from [MN 81](https://suttacentral.net/mn81/en/sujato), who lived in the time of Buddha Kassapa.

From [MN 81](https://suttacentral.net/mn81/en/sujato):

> Ghaṭīkāra has gone for refuge to the Buddha, the teaching, and the
> Saṅgha. He doesn’t kill living creatures, steal, commit sexual
> misconduct, lie, or take alcoholic drinks that cause negligence. He
> has experiential confidence in the Buddha, the teaching, and the
> Saṅgha, and has the ethics loved by the noble ones. He is free of
> doubt regarding suffering, its origin, its cessation, and the practice
> that leads to its cessation. He eats in one part of the day; he’s
> celibate, ethical, and of good character. He has set aside gems and
> gold, and rejected gold and money. He’s put down the shovel and
> doesn’t dig the earth with his own hands. He takes what has crumbled
> off by a riverbank or been dug up by mice, and brings it back in a
> carrier. When he has made a pot, he says, “Anyone may leave bagged
> sesame, mung beans, or chickpeas here and take what they wish.” He
> looks after his blind old parents. And since he has ended the five
> lower fetters, Ghaṭīkāra will be reborn spontaneously and will become
> extinguished there, not liable to return from that world.